# Getting rows N through M of a result set using GROUP BY and ORDER BY pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to convert following query to return the specific number of rows from any LOWERBOUND to UPPERBOUND (any N to M).

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    OWNER||','||HOSTNAME OWNER,
    SubStr(FILENAME,InStr(FILENAME,'/',-1)+1,Length(FILENAME)-InStr(FILENAME,'/',-1)+1)  a, 
    To_Date(SubStr(FILENAME,InStr(filename,'_',1)+1,14),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') STARTIME,
    servergrp Server_Group,
    filename, 
    Count(1) b  
  FROM patcheventlog  
  GROUP BY 
    OWNER||','||HOSTNAME ,
    SubStr(FILENAME,InStr(FILENAME,'/',-1)+1,Length(FILENAME)-InStr(FILENAME,'/',-1)+1)  ,  
    To_Date(SubStr(FILENAME,InStr(filename,'_',1)+1,14),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') ,
    servergrp,
    filename  
  order by 
    Startime desc 
)
where  
  rownum<=10
```

By using the aboove rownum concept i can only get the result set from first row to the rownum defined. As above from 1 to 10.

So please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: @anishroniyar..insetad of rownum use row_number() over partition by ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample for reference. We need to do the following:

```
select * from (
select OWNER,a,STARTIME,Server_Group,filename,b ,row_number() over (order by STARTIME desc ) rnm from
(
  SELECT 
    OWNER||','||HOSTNAME OWNER,
    SubStr(FILENAME,InStr(FILENAME,'/',-1)+1,Length(FILENAME)-InStr(FILENAME,'/',-1)+1)  a, 
To_Date(SubStr(FILENAME,InStr(filename,'_',1)+1,14),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') STARTIME,
    servergrp Server_Group,
    filename, 
    Count(1) b  
  FROM patcheventlog  
  GROUP BY 
    OWNER||','||HOSTNAME ,
    SubStr(FILENAME,InStr(FILENAME,'/',-1)+1,Length(FILENAME)-InStr(FILENAME,'/',-1)+1)  ,  
    To_Date(SubStr(FILENAME,InStr(filename,'_',1)+1,14),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') ,
    servergrp,
    filename 
   ORDER BY 
    Startime desc )
) WHERE rnm BETWEEN 2 AND 7
```

Comment: thanks for the query but this query is setting all the values of rnm column to 1. It doesn't set the rnm column serially. So anything in this?

Comment: @anishroniyar..actually i have used all columns in partition clause ..to generate row_number serially use column in partition clause whose value is same in all rows...

Comment: yes i have edited it. Thanks for your help friend.

Comment: @anishroniyar..here is fiddle for direction...http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/67833/1

Comment: @anishroniyar..glad to help you..:)

Comment: thanks man i got it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93955/discussion-between-anishroniyar-and-anwaar-hell).